# How not to get empty error message after running code from tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, messagebox

I'm writing a Python/Tkinter text editor that (among other things) will run Tkinter scripts. If they don't work right, it will display the resulting error message in a messagebox. My problem is that it also displays a blank error message with "{ }" when the child process window is closed. Is there a way to get the real error messages but not the blank ones?

Here are the relevant lines of code (tx is the text widget, currentfile is the script name, and subprocess is imported as sub):

```
def runcode(*arg):
    global tx, currentfile
    saveit = "Code must be saved before it can be run"
    if currentfile:
         if tx.edit_modified():
             file_save()
    else:
         messagebox.showinfo(message=saveit)
         file_saveas()
    # Catch error messages:
    p = sub.Popen(currentfile, stderr=sub.PIPE)
    errors = p.communicate()
    # Strip out word "None" from beginning:
    boobits = errors[1:]
    if boobits:
        messagebox.showerror(message=boobits)
```

Comment: What does `boobits` look like?

Comment: Example, when I put "def" in the script with nothing after it to evoke an error message: `code`{ File "/home/davidmc/Computing/python/texttest.py", line 117

Comment: Ok, but in that situation what does `boobits` contain? We can't run your code to find out for ourselves since it's not a [mcve].

Comment: When the child process window is closed, the blank error message displayed (i.e., boobits) is { }. When I turn this into a string, it looks like this: (b",). Sorry I can't give a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (at least right now), but that would involve putting a complete script into the text widget to get the error message, and that in turn would seem to involve a lot of code that's not relevant to my problem! When there's an actual error in the code, boobits (the "stderr" output minus the word "None") is displayed with curly braces around it.

Comment: That's odd. `{}` is an empty `dict`, but `(b'',)` is a one-element tuple containing an empty string. However, `(b",)` contains an unterminated string constant; hopefully that's just a typo and you really meant `(b'',)`. And if that's the case you test can be `if boobits and boobits[0]:`, or maybe just `if boobits[0]:`

Comment: It's hard to tell a double quote from two single ones in the messagebox. But I tried `if boobits[0]:` and it worked--no more empty error message! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll turn my comment into a proper answer.

Comment: What is the actual and complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is an empty dict, but `(b'',)` is a one-element tuple containing an empty string. So your test can be

```
if boobits[0]:
```

It's safer to do

```
if boobits and boobits[0]:
```

if it's possible for `boobits` to be an empty tuple, but you probably don't need to worry about that in this case.

Comment: I'm thinking `{}` and (b'',) are as empty as it's going to get, so `if boobits[0]:` should be OK. And I've decided to dump the messagebox in favor of a little auxiliary text widget in a toplevel, to get two advantages: (1) with the cursor, I'll be able to tell `''` from `"`; (2) more importantly, the user will be able to copy and paste error messages. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While `{}` can represent an empty dictionary like some of the comments to the question suggest, it is also how Tcl represents an empty element in a list. Tkinter is just a think wrapper around a Tcl/tk interpreter.

What is actually happening is that you're passing a tuple to the dialog where it expects a string. This list is being converted to a tcl list by Tkinter, and then the widget is creating a string representation of the tcl list, which is `{}` (because the conversion happens in the Tcl interpreter rather than the python interpreter)

The solution is simple: convert your list to a string before passing it to the dialog, or pass in the first element of the list (eg: `messagebox.showerror(message=boobits[0])`

Comment: I think the "list" is actually a tuple, which I don't recall that Tcl has--but maybe Tcl treats tuples as lists when it gets them from Python. I did try converting it to a string, but I still got the messagebox with `(b'',)` in it. But with `messagebox.showerror(message=boobits[0])` I didn't get the unwanted empty error message any more. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I guess it helps to know a bit about Tcl/tk when doing Tkinter stuff. :)